# regex capture bind parameters following a colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match substrings that follow colons : without matching the colon as well. It should be really simple. Given

```
select * from table where name=:name, id = :id order by :order_by limit :limit
```

it should match

```
name
id
order_by
limit
```

However, it's matching

```
:name
:id
:order_by
:limit
```

The regex I'm using is

```
:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

but I've also tried

```
(?::)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How are you using it (and in which language)? You don't seem to extract the capturing groups from the results, but only get a list of all (whole) matches - the regexes you have should both work

Comment: I agree with @Bergi, the regexp is OK, it matches :(something) you need to extract the group i.e. the "something" in ().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexes should work. Assuming you are using JavaScript, you can collect you findings like this in the `matches` array:

```
var myRe = /:(\w+)/g;
var str = "select * from table where name=:name, id = :id order by :order_by limit :limit";
var matches = [];
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(myArray[1]);
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6CB5Y/1/

`myArray` is an array containing the whole match (e.g. ':name') and all its parenthesized substring matches, if any (e.g. 'name'). So use `myArray[1]` to just collect the parenthesized match.

Comment: Also explains why I was only ever getting one result :]

Answer (score 1):

The non-capturing parentheses are still used to the form the `$0` or full match, i.e.

```
:name
+---+ 0
 +--+ 1
```

You probably want to perform a replacement on those place holders, so I would solve the lack of look-behind by using a replacement function:

```
var bound = {
    name: 'test',
    id: 'world',
    order_by: 'col',
    limit: 123
},
sql = 'select * from table where name=:name, id = :id order by :order_by limit :limit';

sql.replace(/:(\w+)/g, function($0, $1) {
    // TODO apply escaping
    return bound[$1]; // perform lookup using 'name', 'id', etc.
});
// "select * from table where name=test, id = world order by col limit 123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a "look behind":

```
(?<=:)\w+
```

A look behind asserts, but does not capture, what comes before the match.

Note the the *whole* match (not group 1 as in your regex) is your target.

Also notice the simplification: `\w` means exactly `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` .

[See this regex running on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/x0XbtD63H7)

Comment: OP seems to use JavaScript, where lookbehind is not supported :-(

Comment: Dear downvoter. The JavaScript tag has only recently been added to the question

Comment: The reference to MDN has always been there though.